# ¿Activar JavaScript en Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

Tengo una página web en la que uso JavaScript para hacer transiciones en diderentes elementos, me funciona en todos los navegadores menos en Internet Explorer y tengo activo el uso de JavaScript.
El código sería el siguiente:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
var desplazamientoActual = $(document).scrollTop();
var foto1 = $("#foto-1");
var foto2 = $("#babyyoda");
var servicio2 = $("#servicio-2");
var servicio3 = $("#servicio-3");
var servicio4 = $("#servicio-4");
var repoAnim = $("#repo-anim");
var repoBoda = $("#repo-boda");

if (desplazamientoActual > 30) {
    $("#header").css({
        "background-color": "rgb(45, 45, 45)",
        "position": "fixed",
        "width": "100%",
    });

    if (window.innerWidth <= 700) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].style.paddingTop = "12em";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].style.paddingTop = "9em";
    }
}

if (desplazamientoActual < 30) {
    $("#header").css({
        "background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)",
        "position": "static",
        "width": "auto",
    });
    document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].style.paddingTop = "0.1em";

}

if (window.innerWidth <= 1077 && window.innerWidth > 700) {

    if (desplazamientoActual > 3600 && repoAnim.css("display") == "none") {
        repoAnim.fadeIn(1200);
    }
} else if(window.innerWidth > 1077) {
    if (desplazamientoActual > 1970 && repoAnim.css("display") == "none") {
        repoAnim.fadeIn(1200);
    }
}
```

He pensado que igual es por que las funciones que utilizo no las soporta Internet Explorer.
Alguna idea?

Comment: Qué quieres decir con que no funciona?

Comment: A que no se termina de ejecutar el código de JavaScript y las transiciones para visualizar las imágenes no se cargan.

Comment: Sale algún error en la consola del navegador? Qué versión de IE estás intentando usar?

Comment: No me salen errores en la consola del navegador, ni warnings... La versión que estoy usando es la 11.

Comment: El titulo no tiene nada que ver con el contenido, no?

Comment: Se supone que ya está activado JavaScript en Internet Explorer, lo he mirado en los ajustes.

Comment: crea un css no lo agreges a nivel de Javascript y luego con javascript quitas/agregas la clase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo resolví, probé de nuevo pero desde otro ordenador esta parte

> Si no, agrega console.log en diferentes partes del código para saber lo que está haciendo IE

Y al parecer, en una de las primeras líneas estaba usando un `SmoothScroll` que no es compatible con IE, así que lo he aislado para que no se meta en esa parte del código si se abre desde un navegador IE.

Gracias a todos por las respuestas!

Comment: Si esto dio solución a tu problema por favor no olvides marcar como aceptada tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Añade lo siguiente en la etiqueta head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>
```

El primero se debe a la acentuación y el segundo a resolver estos problemas de compatibilidad con IE.

Comment: Esto no me lo solucionó, sigue sin ejecutarse :(

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiando el evento a `window` en vez de `document`:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    ...
});
```

Si aún sigue sin funcionar es probable que requieras agregar un evento adicional:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        ...
    });
};
```

Comment: No me lo solucionó...

Comment: Cambiaste también en la primera línea? Es decir: `var desplazamientoActual = $(window).scrollTop();`. Si no, agrega `console.log` en diferentes partes del código para saber lo que está haciendo IE